# Partial Application of Infix Functions in F#

Tags: haskell, f#, func

In haskell it is posible to partially apply an infix function using sections, for instance given the infix function < (less than) one can partially apply any of the function's arguments:  (5 <) , (< 5)

In other words, in haskell we have the following shorthand notation:

```
op :: a -> b -> c
(`op` y) === \x -> x `op` y
(x `op`) === \y -> x `op` y
```

Does F# have a similar concept?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, neither of those (apart from standard partial application like `(=) x`).

---

Whereas I like the succinctness of `Seq.find ((=) x)`, things like `Seq.filter ((<) 3)` (or even `Seq.map (flip (-) 1)`) are simply awkward to read and should immediately be replaced by a lambda expression, imo.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. It's just that coming from haskell where filter (< 5) [1..10] yields [1,2,3,4], it confuses me that in F# List.filter ((<) 5) [1..10] returns [6;7;8;9;10]!

Comment: Well, that's my definition of '(really) awkward' ;)

Comment: primodemus: `<` is an operator, so you can write it out like this `(<) 5 10` which means the same thing as `5 < 10`. Likewise, `List.filter ((<) 5)` means the same thing as `List.filter (fun x -> 5 < x)`. I can understand how easy it is to read the code as "filter list for items less than 5", but I wouldn't consider that a gotcha.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to invent your own standards...

```
let lsection x f y -> f x y
let rsection f y x -> f x y
```

Then `lsection 5 (<) === (5 <)` and `rsection (<) 5 === (< 5)`.

Though really, without language support, just put a lambda in there and it'll be clearer.